# Aliases htaccess wildcard redirect http and https requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all of these urls that are requested from both http and https protocol to be redirected to `https://www.example.com`:

```
example.com
example.com.au
www.example.com.au
example.co.nz
www.example.co.nz
example.co.uk
www.example.co.uk
example.net
www.example.net
example.net.au
www.example.net.au
example.org
www.example.org
```

I tried this first, but it doesn't redirect the urls requested on https protocol.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com.au [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com.au [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.nz [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.co.nz [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.co.uk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.net.au [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.net.au [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.org
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I tried this next, but it doesnt redirect urls that has `www` in them.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I use a wildcard that redirects URLs from all aliases domain names  on both http and https to `https://www.example.com`?

**UPDATE:**

Trial of rewrite rule with `!` wildcard as per @CBroe comment below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Further to @starkeen comment, since I want to redirect both http and https requests to the said url, I have added 2 sets of url in my htaccess. First one is to rewrite all http to https and the second one to redirect if it doesnt match the said url:

```
# Force to use HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Use one single condition to check that the host is _not_ `www.example.com` ...?

Comment: thats probably easier. can you give me a sample please?

Comment: You can make any RewriteCond pattern an non-matching one by prefxing it with a `!`, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: I have updated my question with the trail I did with `!`. I tried a rewrite condition but it doesnt work. Can you point out what I have got wrong here please?

Comment: The update rewrite partly works for all other domain aliases. But it doesnt redirect the domains with `example.com.au`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Since I want the redirect to work for both http and https request, I have added 2 rules. First one to redirect http to https and the second one to redirect if it doesnt match the url. I have updated my question with my new rewrite rules. Can you tell if I am implementing it correctly? Thank you starkeen!

Comment: Try the updated rule I have combined your 2 rules into a single rule. R is a temporary Redirect status. Change it to R=301 to make the redirect permanent.

Comment: Perfect!! Its so simple. I was overcomplicating it. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! You have helped me heaps. Much obliged!!